# Creating a Rails 3 HABTM with Active Admin throws a 'Can't mass-assign protected attributes:' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am a rails noob so the below is probably down to lack of understanding however I have been looking/reading all day and cannot seem to find the solution.

I have two models - project and technology :

**Project :**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible description, :name

  has_and_belongs_to_many :technologies, :join_table => :projects_technologies

end
```

**Technology :**

```
class Technology < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :abbr, :description, :name

  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects, :join_table => :projects_technologies

end
```

**My Create_Projects_Technologies migration was as follows :**

```
class CreateProjectsTechnologies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up

    create_table :projects_technologies, :id => false do |t|
        t.references :project
        t.references :technology
    end
    add_index :projects_technologies, [:project_id, :technology_id]
    add_index :projects_technologies, [:technology_id, :project_id]
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :projects_technologies
  end
end
```

I am then using Active Admin to create and edit Project models using the following form :

```
ActiveAdmin.register Project do

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Project attributes" do
      f.input :name
      f.input :description
      f.input :technologies, as: :check_boxes
    end
    f.buttons
  end

end
```

This correctly shows all my technologies as check boxes however as soon as I submit the form I hit the following error which I have not been able to overcome :

**ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in Admin::ProjectsController#update**

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: technology_ids
```

All help is very much appreciate :D

Comment: In case anyone else gets this error mine came up `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: #{attrs.join}` rather than having the `category_ids`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple add technology_ids to Project attr_accessible

```
attr_accessible :client, :description, :name, :technology_ids
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I missed that. Something about not seeing the forest because of all the trees :P

Comment: but what about mass assignment? i mean, i understand that because of this is an admin area nobody without special rights can do anything but still this doesn't look right. (i'm talking about adding technology_ids to attr_accessible)